# Getting boolean instead of record when authorizing with Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

According to [the Pundit readme](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#policies) `authorize` should return the record, yet when I'm calling it I'm getting `true`.

> authorize returns the object passed to it, so you can chain it like
>   this:
>
> Controller:
>
> ```
> def show
>   @user = authorize User.find(params[:id])
> end
> ```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.3'
gem 'pundit', '~> 1.1'
```

My controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :index]
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    # just for debugging purposes
    raise "Post is a #{@post.class.name}!" unless @post.is_a? Post
  end

  def set_post
    # this should return an instance of post
    @post = authorize Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Policy:

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.all
    end
  end

  def show?
    true
  end

  # ...
end
```

Spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "Posts", type: :request do
  subject { response }

  describe "GET /posts/:id" do
    let!(:post) { create(:post) }
    before { get post_path(post) }
    it { should be_successful }
  end
end
```

Failure message:

```
  4) Posts GET /posts/:id 
     Failure/Error: raise "Post is a #{@post.class.name}!" unless @post.is_a? Post

     RuntimeError:
       Post is a TrueClass!
```

While its pretty simple to remedy this by:

```
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id]).tap do |p|
    @post = Post.find(params[:id]).tap { |r| authorize r }
  end
end
```

Im very curious as to why its not working as stated by the readme. Is this a bug or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the record is apparently a change in the master that is not reflected in the [1.1](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/blob/b0bdfbc0db601ea4cc6cfcb243a657396c3e0f82/lib/pundit.rb) release.

```
# Retrieves the policy for the given record, initializing it with the
# record and user and finally throwing an error if the user is not
# authorized to perform the given action.
#
# @param user [Object] the user that initiated the action
# @param record [Object] the object we're checking permissions of
# @param record [Symbol] the query method to check on the policy (e.g. `:show?`)
# @raise [NotAuthorizedError] if the given query method returned false
# @return [true] Always returns true
def authorize(user, record, query)
  policy = policy!(user, record)

  unless policy.public_send(query)
    raise NotAuthorizedError, query: query, record: record, policy: policy
  end

  true
end
```

A workaround is:

```
def authorize(record, query = nil)
  super
  record 
end
```